# finding polynomials to approximate a multivariable function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, polynomials

Let $U := B_1(0) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, with $B_1(0) := \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\space \|(x, y)\| _1 < 1\}$. Now consider the function:

$$g: U \to \mathbb{R}^2, (x, y) \mapsto \frac{1}{1-x-y}$$

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, I now want to find a polynomial function $p_n$, so that $g(x, y) = p_n(x, y) + o(\|(x, y)\|^n)$ for $(x, y) \to 0$.

(Where $o(\cdots)$ is the "Small O" Landau symbol.)

I must admit that I don't really know how to approach this. What's the technique or formula to determine these polynomials?

Comment: I see several issues in your question. First $g$ is not defined on $B_1(0)$, i.e. at point $(1/2,1/2)$. Second is $o(\|(x, y)\|^n)$ at a given point or for all the points of the unit ball? Lastly, are you sure that you want to bound the difference by this power $n$ quantity?

Comment: Well, that's how the question was given to me. Except that $B_1(0)$ was defined without clarification of which norm it actually is, so I naturally assumed it was the Euclidian norm. When instead defining it using the $||.||_1$-norm, it wouldn't contain any undefined points, would it?

Comment: Using $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ is  better as you don't have anymore undefined point. However still $g$ will be unbounded. You don't have clarification on my third point?

Comment: To the 2nd: to me, the Landau notation was always defined with a limit, and the limit in this case it's $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$. So I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question in this regard. $o(||(x, y)||^n)$ denotes that $g(x, y) - p_n(x, y) < k||(x, y)||^n \forall k > 0$ when $(x, y)$ are sufficiently close to $(0, 0)$; that was the definition given to me if I recall correctly. To the last point, well yes, that is how the question was given to me.

Comment: As I intuitively understand it: the $o(||(x, y)^n||$ denotes how large the difference between the function $g$ and the approximating polynomial $f$ can only be; and with growing $n$, $p_n$ must approximate $g$ better and better, so for any given "accuracy" or largest error, one must find a polynomial that approximates $g$ well enough. That's my interpretation or intuition at least; I still don't know how to solve it though. If you still think that $o(||(x, y)||^n)$ shouldn't stand there as it is, then more details on why this can't be would of course also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I finally understood. You're requested to work only locally around the origin. Not to make an approximation on the full "ball".

If that is the case, the Taylor expansion of $g$ at the origin $(0,0)$ up to order $n$ will answer the question.

For this you can have a look at [Taylor series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html). You'll need to compute $$\frac{\partial^{h+k} g}{\partial x^h \partial y^k}(0,0)$$ for $0 \le h+k \le n$ by induction.